# Material-UI: the key `default` provided to the classes property is not implemented in Checkbox

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

Using material Ui in my react js application.
with version:-
"material-ui": "^0.20.0",
"mui-datatables": "1.1.5",

Trying to integrate Data table and passing this configuration in this piece of code.

```
    const options = {
    filter: false,
    selectableRows: true,
    filterType: 'multiselect',
    print: false,
    download: false,
    responsive: 'stacked',
    onRowsSelect: (rowsSelected, allRows) => {
        console.log(rowsSelected, allRows);
    },
};
class Dashboard extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="">
                <List data={data} column={columns} option={options}></List>               
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

whenever I pass " selectableRows: true," in options it gives warning at browser's console.

```
        Warning: Material-UI: the key `default` provided to the classes property is not implemented in Checkbox.
    You can only override one of the following: root,checked,disabled,colorPrimary,colorSecondary


Warning: Material-UI: the key `checkedPrimary` provided to the classes property is not implemented in Checkbox.
You can only override one of the following: 
root,checked,disabled,colorPrimary,colorSecondary

Warning: Material-UI: the key `checkedSecondary` provided to the classes property is not implemented in Checkbox.
You can only override one of the following: root,checked,disabled,colorPrimary,colorSecondary
```

Comment: Provide a key property in List component.

Comment: Tried but not worked.Same warnings display.

Comment: Why have you added this options to the List component and not to the MUIDataTable?